# Generate all permutations of processor-task distribution?

Tags: java, scheduling, task

could someone help me with function which check all permutations of task scheduling problem? I have array with task where index is identity of task and value is task time and array with N processor. I need a functions which generates all possibilites of schedule this taks on that processors.

Comment: Appears to be a double post of your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684104/exact-algorithm-for-task-scheduling-on-n-identical-processors

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking a person who know how do it, everyone knows what to do but I know it and I, nobody help how to do it.

Comment: @przemek. Solving this by generating all permutations would be NP complete problem. Sure you could find all permutations but it will take longer than executing tasks on N process with 'not so ideal' distribution. I recommend to use greedy algorithm for such task scheduling. Also I was wondering (Peter already asked this questions) why you couldn't you ExecutorService? P.S. I could post solutions with all permutations/greedy implementation if you like, but having answer to question above would help me to understand better your need.

Comment: @Przemek I believe I've answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684104/exact-algorithm-for-task-scheduling-on-n-identical-processors/4685956#4685956

Comment: Yes Bolo I used algorithm which You entered, it works perfectly, exactly I was wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Perto I have to implement exact algorith which find optimal Cmax, this is theoretical problem, not practical :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for an exact algorithm, take a look at the branch and bound algorithm. But since it can take ages anyway, why not simply try every possible combination one by one (brute force)?